# How to close the channel in a concurrent operation?

Tags: go, concurrency, channel

I wrote a go code like that about concurrency and channels ⤵️

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

var links = []string{
    "https://mcevik.com",
    "https://stackoverflow.com",
    "https://www.linkedin.com",
    "https://github.com",
    "https://medium.com",
    "https://kaggle.com",
}

func getLink(link string, ch chan string) {
    if res, err := http.Get(link); err != nil {
        ch <- err.Error()
    } else {
        ch <- fmt.Sprintf("[%d] - %s", res.StatusCode, link)
    }
}

func main() {
    ch := make(chan string, len(links))

    for _, link := range links {
        go getLink(link, ch)
    }

    for msg := range ch {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Uz_k8KI6bKt

and the output is like that ⤵️

[image: output]

---

In the output we see that the program is not terminated. The reason for the program's not terminated is that the channel has not closed and therefore cannot exit the loop.

How can I close the channel and fix the code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refactored it by adding [WaitGroup](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup) to `getLink` method,

```golang
func getLink(link string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan string)
```

and channel closed after `wg.Wait()` call.

```golang
go func() {
    wg.Wait()
    close(ch)
}()
```

---

As a result, the final version of the code looks like this ⤵️

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "sync"
)

var links = []string{
    "https://mcevik.com",
    "https://stackoverflow.com",
    "https://www.linkedin.com",
    "https://github.com",
    "https://medium.com",
    "https://kaggle.com",
}

func getLink(link string, wg *sync.WaitGroup, ch chan string) {
    defer wg.Done()

    if res, err := http.Get(link); err != nil {
        ch <- err.Error()
    } else {
        ch <- fmt.Sprintf("[%d] - %s", res.StatusCode, link)
    }
}

func main() {
    wg := sync.WaitGroup{}
    ch := make(chan string, len(links))

    for _, link := range links {
        wg.Add(1)
        go getLink(link, &wg, ch)
    }

    go func() {
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()

    for msg := range ch {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/741F8eHrhFP

Answer (score 1):

use a [WaitGroup](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup) to watch for writes completion.

```
    ch := make(chan string, len(links))
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    for _, link := range links {
        wg.Add(1)
        go func(){
            getLink(link, ch)
            wg.Done()
        }()
    }
```

Use another routine to listen that event and close the channel.

```
    go func(){
        wg.Wait()
        close(ch)
    }()
    for msg := range ch {
        fmt.Println(msg)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks but did you test your code, your code is giving wrong output

Answer (score 0):

If you start exactly N (ie `len(links)`) Go routines, all of which will necessarily send back a message, then the simplest thing is to read exactly N messages from the channel before closing it.

Don't `range` over the channel; that's most useful when you don't know how many items you'll receive and you want to read until the channel is closed. Instead loop a given number of times:

```golang
// main:

for _ = range links {
    fmt.Println(<-ch)
}

close(ch)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but I don't want to check the value inside the channel like this.
With array size I can also control but I want to do this control with channel. Can such a control be done with the channel, is such an improvement possible?

Comment: Of course you can control this with a channel, but you wouldn't. That is not how you would solve the problem in your question. If you have a different question, you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: the channel should be closed after its writes completed, not once you have drained it. It is a conceptual mistake.